# Server side pagination for jQuery Datatable

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, pagination, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTable (from: https://www.datatables.net) to show data in tabular form.
I want to enable server side pagination as the data is in millions of records.
With the below code I am able to get the client pagination.
I am not sure how to enable server side pagination.
Here is my code.

Javascript Code

```
var emailSearchObject = {};
emailSearchObject.fromEmail = jQuery('#txtFromEmail').val();
emailSearchObject.toEmail = jQuery('#txtToEmail').val();
emailSearchObject.PageSize = "20";
emailSearchObject.PageNumber = "1";

var emailSearchObjectJson = JSON.stringify(searchObject);

jQuery.ajax({
    type        : "POST",
    dataType    : 'json',
    url         : '/server/mypage.aspx/getEmailData',
    data        : "{search:" + emailSearchObjectJson + "}",
    contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success     : function (result) {
        alert("Success");
        jQuery('#divLogTable').DataTable({
            //serverSide: true,
            //ajax: {
            //   url: "/server/mypage.aspx/getEmailData",",
            //   type: "POST"
            //},
            data    : result.d,
            columns : [
                { data : 'fromAddress' },
                { data : 'toAddress' },
                { data : 'status' }
            ]
        });
    },
    error : function (err) {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

C# code

```
[WebMethod]
public static object[] Search(SearchClass search)
{
    var service = new EmailService();
    return service.Search(search).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: I don't have time to fully check it out, but it seems it is plausible going off this page:  https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

Comment: I tried that, check my commented code, but its throwing error.

Comment: You should try including the error above, I didn't read anything about an error.  I've not ever tried this personally, was just trying to point you in the right direction.

Comment: I am getting "Cannot reinitialize the Datatable" error

Comment: What do you mean by server side pagination? Do you want to get the current page of the client DT in your webmethod?

Comment: instead of doing client side pagination , I want to do server side pagination. At a time I want to get only one thousand records.

Comment: Please use pipelining if you only want a certain number of pages to be loaded and cached : https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/pipeline.html